# Beth Numbers and their relation to Aleph Numbers

Tags: notation, set-theory

I have been looking into Alephs and Beths, and while I understand Alephs quite well I would feel, I do not fully understand Beths or what makes them different from Alephs. Can somebody please explain to me what makes them different, as I know that Aleph(0) = Beth(0), but I also know that that doesn't really mean anything when it comes to higher examples of it.

So can somebody give a description of this difference.

Comment: In the absence of the continuum hypotheses, we know that $\aleph_1\leq \beth_1$, but we do not know if they are equal. The continuum hypothesis is the statement that $\aleph_1=\beth_1$. The Generalized Continuum Hypothesis is the assertion that the $\aleph$s and the $\beth$s are the same.

Answer (score 1):

The aleph numbers are defined as thus:

- For ordinals $\alpha$ define $\omega_\alpha$ viz. $\omega_0:=\omega$, $\omega_\gamma:=\bigcup_{\beta\in\gamma}\omega_\beta$ for limit ordinals $\gamma>0$, and $\omega_{\alpha^+}$ is the [Hartogs number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number#Proof) of $\omega_\alpha$, i.e. the least ordinal not injectable into it;
- $\aleph_\alpha$ is $\omega_\alpha$ construed as a cardinal, i.e. it's "how many" elements $\omega_\alpha$ has.

The beth numbers are the following construed as cardinals (raising some subtleties as to how, but we won't go into them for now):

- $\beth_0:=\aleph_0$;
- $\beth_{\alpha^+}:=\mathcal{P}(\beth_\alpha)$;
- $\beth_\gamma:=\bigcup_{\beta\in\gamma}\beth_\beta$ for limit ordinals $\gamma>0$.

The generalized continuum hypothesis ($\mathsf{GCH}$) states all ordinals $\alpha$ satisfy $\aleph_\alpha=\beth_\alpha$; the special case $\alpha=1$ (i.e. $\alpha=\{\emptyset\}$) is the continuum hypothesis ($\mathsf{CH}$).

Both statements are undecidable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (if it's consistent, a parenthetical aside hereafter always implied), a popular axiomatic set theory. This theory is obtained by adding the axiom of choice ($\mathsf{AC}$) to Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory ($\mathsf{ZF}$), in which $\mathsf{AC}$ is undecidable. But $\mathsf{AC}$ at least implies each $\beth_\alpha$ is $\aleph_\beta$ for some ordinal $\beta\ge\alpha$.

If $\kappa,\,\lambda$ are cardinal numbers, at least one of them transfinite, $\kappa^\lambda$ is [mostly undetermined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem) in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (although $\mathsf{AC}$ implies $\kappa^2=\kappa$ for all transfinite $\kappa$, which can be used to deduce much of what $\mathsf{ZFC}$ implies). For example, $2^{\aleph_0}$ can be $\aleph_n$ for any finite $n\ge1$, although it can't be $\aleph_\omega$ even in $\mathsf{ZF}$.

However, the case where any transfinite cardinals among $\kappa,\,\lambda$ are beth numbers are especially tractable. For example, if $\kappa=2^\mu$ with $\lambda,\,\mu$ beth numbers and $\mu\ge\lambda$, $\kappa^\lambda=\kappa$.

Comment: Your last statement isn't true. For instance, $\beth_\omega^{\beth_0} >\beth_\omega.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I've edited. Apparently, $\beth_\omega^{\beth_0}\ne\sup_{n\in\omega}\beth_n^{\beth_0}$ (I guess I was thinking of unions). In the interest of dealing with an outstanding case, what's the right way to evaluate $\beth_\omega^{\beth_0}$?

Comment: @J.G. $\beth_{\omega+1}$. Cardinal exponentiation is notoriously discontinuous.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What's the proof?

Comment: Note that $\beth_\omega^{\beth_0}$ is the same cardinality as $\prod_{n<\omega}\beth_{n+1}$. Next, take any subset of $\beth_\omega$, and consider its trace on the interval $[\beth_n,\beth_{n+1})$. Finally, note that there are $\beth_{n+1}$ subsets of $\beth_n$, so by enumerating them, any function "chooses" a subset. (This is a very telegraphic version of the idea, if you want a more elaborate answer, I think it might exist on this site already.)

Comment: @J.G. Also, in lieu of calculating it exactly you can get the inequality from Konig’s theorem.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What about just $$\beth_\omega^{\beth_0}=\prod_n \beth_{n+1}=\prod_n 2^{\beth_n} = 2^{\sum_n\beth_n}=2^{\beth_\omega}=\beth_{\omega+1} $$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: Sure, if you want to be quick about it. :-) (Having said that, I do think that my argument, which is essentially the underlying argument to the whole equation there, is eye opening.)